# JavaScript. Как отформатировать строку

Tags: javascript

С сервера приходит строка в таком виде:

```
'Заражено187 859+10699'
```

Как отформатировать ее, чтобы у строки стал читабельный вид:

```
'Заражено: 187 859 (+10699)'
```

В голову приходит использовать цепочку replace(), но это очень неудобно, может есть решение попроще

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const str = 'Заражено187 859+10699';
const [amount, newCases] = str.match(/([\d ]+)/g);
const resultStr = `Заражено: ${amount} +(${newCases})`;


console.log(resultStr)
```